# Extend method of Python list

Tags: python, list

Why does this

```
list(('a', 'b', 'c')).extend([1, 2, 3])
```

evaluate to '**None**'.
What I mean is that the result of a constructor should be a list, so there should be no problem "extending" it, just like if I would've assigned the result of the constructor to a variable and then extended, still the result is almost always a None.
So why does this happen.

Comment: @vaultah Please close the question, if you have the privileges.

Comment: I can't, since I edited the tags. There should be a button saying "That solved my problem", you should click it

Comment: That button isn't there.

Answer (score -1):

`L = list(('a', 'b', 'c'))` will create a list and assign it to the variable `L`. Similarly, `list(('a', 'b', 'c'))` will create a new list.

`L.extend([1,2,3])` will perform an operation on L, with a return value of `None`.

So what's happening in your case is that the constructor creates a list, on which you call `extend`. Since `extend` has a return value of `None`, `list(('a', 'b', 'c')).extend([1, 2, 3])` evaluates to `None`. Since the list you constructed (namely `list(('a', 'b', 'c'))`) wasn't assigned to a variable, there are no references to it, and python's refcounting garbage collector just sweeps up that list after the call to `extend`, which returns `None`

Comment: Why did you choose to answer this question? It's obviously a duplicate, and you could close it as such with your dupe hammer.

Comment: @vaultah: didn't see the dup target before I answered. Was just trying to be helpful